# Cross Streets Calculation

Tags: php, coordinates, coordinate-systems

How can I get the cross street names of one particular street?

Lets say I am on a street name B and I want to get two street either side of street B. I also have co-ordinates for the street B.

I think this can be achieved using calculation over co-ordinates. How?

If B street has Lon: 40.4325342 and Lat: -72.5346344, can I get the nearest street of one side of street B by making arithmetic operations to Lon and Lat?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Googles Reverse Geocoding API to get the next street to given coordinates:

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2008/10/geocoding-in-reverse.html

This however would be a client side solution with JavaScript.

Comment: oh.. its also availible on the server side: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html#GeocodingRequests

Comment: Google also has a general API for that: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: are you guys sure I can get the Cross Streets by this API?

Comment: You can get the Streetname to the coordinates. To get the next street you can do something like increasing lat/lon and see if you hit a new streetname. If not, increase a little more.

Answer (score 0):

You could even build you own database to do such calculations. Spatial Database is the one designed to do it. Major databases (e.g., MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server) have some spatial extensions for this purpose. Then you could use ST_Crosses(A, B) to determine whether A crosses B, then you could retrive the name beased on the result.